# Is there something as "Vector Regression", instead of having just one numerical responsable variable I have multiple of them?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I'm interested in predicting the sequence of the order of the events in an individual giving a bunch of predictive variables using Machine Learning. So my guess is, for an specific instance with around 10 predictive variables, I write the rank of each event (Let's say that there are 6 of them (Event A, B, C, D, E and F), (for example Event A = 5 because it was the fifth).

If I have a new individual with his info (his 10 predictive variables) then I apply regression to every of event rank variable individually, I will obtain for each of them a number between 1 and 6, and for each of them I will guess the sequence.

I guess it must be a more intelligent way of predicting the sequence but I don't know how.

Comment: This sounds like a few different possible tasks; could you make the example a little more concrete (e.g., what are the events of interest, why are they ordered, what a single training example would look like)?

Comment: @Firebug Why did you suppress the "traminer" tag? With the answer given, this thread is clearly relevant for the TraMineR community!

Comment: @Gilbert the question is not about `traminer`, so that's why. Otherwise other people answering would feel like they need to offer a `traminer`-based answer, which is very clearly not the case here

Comment: @Firebug OK, but then people browsing the `traminer` tag will miss this question that could be relevant for them.

Comment: No @Gilbert, this question is not necessarily relevant to them, since the question does not even mention the toolkit. Taking this to an extreme, imagine if everyone adding an answer with a different toolset were to add their tags to questions that did not ever mention the tool.

Comment: @User1865345 You removed the `sequence-analysis` tag. Without this tag, I would have missed the question and seems the question would have no answer. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: Of course not, @Gilbert. The positive votes in your answer indicate the community's appreciation of the same. Removal of a tag or so is not tantamount to receiving or withdrawal of an answer. As for the specific tag, see this Meta [post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/what-to-do-with-the-sequence-analysis-tag).

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to grow a regression tree of observed sequence orders. (See also this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/623517/11805) to related question.)

If you have a set of observed event sequences, you can compute pairwise dissimilarities between the sequences using some edit distance measure. Then, using the resulting pairwise dissimilarity matrix, you can grow a regression tree of the sequences. You thus partition the sequences into leaves, each characterized by a proper combination of values of the covariates (predictors).  The values of the covariates of a case determine to which leaf of the tree it belongs. However, cases in a leaf do not all have the same order. To predict an order you need to identify a representative order of the leaf such as the medoid or the sequence with the densest neighborhood.

All this can be done in R with the TraMineR and TraMineRextras packages. I illustrate below using the `actcal` monthly activity data included in TraMineR.

```
library(TraMineR)
library(TraMineRextras)

## loading actcal data (one case per line)
data(actcal)

## loading time-stamped event sequences built from the actcal data
## actcal.tse is a vertical file with one event per line
data(actcal.tse)
## creating event sequence object (one sequence per case)
actcal.seqe <- seqecreate(actcal.tse)
## We have 8 different events in this dataset
## assign unit cost for insertion/deletion of each event
idcost <- rep(1, 8)
## computing the dissimilarity matrix
dd <- seqedist(actcal.seqe, idcost=idcost, vparam=.1)
dim(dd)
# [1] 2000 2000

## growing the tree
dtree <- disstree(dd ~ educat00 + civsta00 + age00, data=actcal)
## Plot the tree using parallel coordinate plots for rendering order 
gvpath <- "C:/Program Files/Graphviz"
disstreedisplay(dtree, image.data=actcal.seqe, filename="fg-event-seq-tree",
                image.fun=seqpcplot, show.tree=TRUE, gvpath=gvpath)
```

[image]

To extract representative orders you can use the `dissrep` function. For the above example, where most of the sequences have a single event, medoids are in each leaf a sequence with a single event.

**References**:

For regression trees from a dissimilarity matrix:

Studer, M., G. Ritschard, A. Gabadinho and N.S. Müller (2011), Discrepancy analysis of state sequences, *Sociological Methods and Research*, 40(3), pp. 471-510. doi: [10.1177/0049124111415372](https://doi.org/10.1177/0049124111415372).

For dissimilarities between event sequences:

Ritschard, G., R. Bürgin and M. Studer (2013), Exploratory Mining of Life Event Histories, in J.J. McArdle and G. Ritschard (eds), *Contemporary Issues in Exploratory Data Mining in the Behavioral Sciences*, Quantitative Methodology Series , New York: Routledge, pages 221-253. Preprint ([pdf](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/publications/gr/Ritschard-SHP-life-events.pdf)).

For representative sequences:

Gabadinho, A. and G. Ritschard (2013), Searching for typical life trajectories applied to childbirth histories, in R. Levy and E. Widmer (eds), *Gendered life courses - Between individualization and standardization. A European approach applied to Switzerland*, Vienna-Lit. Pages 287-312. Preprint ([pdf](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/publications/gr/GabadhinoRitschard-TypicalTrajectories2013.pdf)).

For the parallel coordinate plot:

Bürgin, R. and G. Ritschard (2014), A decorated parallel coordinate plot for categorical longitudinal data, *The American Statistician*. Vol. 68(2), 98-103, doi: [10.1080/00031305.2014.887591](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2014.887591).

Comment: Thank you so much. Im looking for more information on this topic. Instead of "vectorial Regression", is there any other common name? I heard sequence analysis but in that case the problem is much different that mine as I see because items can repeat.